# XAuth not working as expected with TightVNC server: “You will require a password to access your desktops.”

Tags: linux, vnc, centos, xauth

I'm trying to get a friend's server started for them. It's running on the same hardware platform as one that I personally use, so I figured it would be easy.

They're running CentOS, and I'm trying to get VNC to work. I picked TightVNC because it's what I use, and installed it. It complained that it couldn't find XAuth, so I installed that, too.

Now when I start the VNC server, it prints the following then exits:

> You will require a password to access your desktops.

I can't get TightVNC to actually accept a password and continue. I suspect this has something to do with XAuth being set up wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you use `vncpasswd` to set the password for the VNC server? Just run `vncpasswd` before you start the VNC server for the first time and enter the password as prompted.

Comment: Sorry about taking a year to mark this correct; I totally forgot about this question. Your answer was, as I recall, the solution to the problem I was having.

Comment: One extra thing that might not be obvious; you need to `chmod 600` the password file (normally ~/.vnc/passwd) that you create using vncpasswd.

Comment: Thanks, `chmod 600 ~/.vnc/passwd` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem, and the answers gave me hints to what was wrong, but we're not exactly the answer.

It turns out that the service was being started as the root user, but I did not have a password as the root user only as my user. I had to `sudo su`, and then run `vncpassword`.

That solved the problem.